# Kafka Connect, JdbcSinkConnector - Getting "Error retrieving Avro schema for id 1, Subject not found.; error code: 40401"

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-nifi, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I have created a NiFi flow that eventually publishes json records as records with Avro encoded values and string keys, using a schema in Confluent Registry for the value schema. Here is the [configuration for the AvroRecordSetWriter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/est5n.png) in NiFi.

I am now trying to use Kafka Connect (`connect-standalone`) to move the messages to a PostgreSQL database using JdbcSinkConnector, but am getting the following error: [Error retrieving Avro schema for id 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpm0r.png)

I have confirmed that I have a schema in my Confluent Registry with and ID of 1.  Following are my configs for the Connect task

**Worker Config:**

```
bootstrap.servers=localhost:29092
key.converter.schemas.enable=false
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
value.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
value.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081
internal.key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/connect.offsets
rest.host.name=localhost
rest.port=8083
plugin.path=share/java
```

**Connector Config:**

```
name=pg-sink
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector
tasks.max=1
topics=rds
connection.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test
connection.user=postgres
connection.password=xxxxxxxx
insert.mode=upsert
table.name.format=test_data
auto.create=true
```

I created a flow in NiFi that consumes the messages properly and I have also successfully consumed messages (which are formated as JSON in the output) with kafka-avro-console-consumer by specifying `--property schema.registry.url=http://schema-registry:8081`. Note that I'm running the consumer within a Docker container, and that is why the url is not localhost.

I'm not sure what I am missing.  My only thought is that I am using the wrong class for the key converter, but that would not make sense with the given error.  Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Nifi can write to Postgres as well. Are you sure you need Kafka Connect and instead do all processing in one location? The error message isn't specific to the value or key, only that the ID cannot be found in the registry for one of the possible `rds` subjects... If you do `GET /subjects` on the registry, you might see what's available. Also, if you're using Connect in Docker it's best to use Distributed mode because offsets shouldn't be stored in an ephemeral environment (a container file system)

Comment: Thanks cricket_007.  I had looked at a processor in NiFi (I don’t recall which) for going to PostgreSQL.  I’ll probably go back to that line of attack.  It looks like PutDatabaseRecord processor might get me there?  Using the REST api for the registry, I did see the schema in the registry with ID=1, so I know it’s in the registry.  Thanks for the tip on using distribute mode, I’ll switch over within Docker.

Comment: No just ID=1, but as the answer below points out, it needs to be under `rds-value` for the Confluent Avro deserialization and converters to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know much about Nifi but I see that the name of the schema is "rds" and in the error logs it's say that it didn't found the subject in the schema registry.

Kafka use `KafkaAvroSerializer` to serialize avro records and in the same time registering the associated avro schema in the schema registry. 
It use `KafkaAvroDeserializer` to deserialize avro records and retrieving the associated schema from the schema registry.

Schema registry store schema into categories called "subjects" and the default behavior to naming the subject for a record is : `topic_name-value` for the value record and `topic_name-key` for the key.

In your case, you didn't register the schema with  Kafka but with Nifi, so my guess will be that the name "rds" appears in or is the subject name on the schema registry.

How did you verify that you schema was corectly stored ?

Normally in your case the correct subject will be `rds-value` because you're using schema registry only on value records.

Comment: Thanks Said. I’m using a reference to a schema in a Confluent registry and storing the id in the encoded Avro records (I *think* that’s how it works with Confluent).  The schema isn’t being registered automatically; I’m creating the schema in the registry beforehand and I know it exists, having id=1 and name “rds”, after querying the registry with the REST interface.  My understanding was that with a Avro record encoded using a Confluent registry, the reference to a schema is determined by the the schema id encoded in the record and not the name of the schema.

Comment: But you have me wondering if the serializer that NiFi uses in the AvroRecordSetWriter service is not the Confluent “flavor” of Avro.

Comment: You're right, schema registry have an API to retrieve the wanted schema by his id and it's this API that it's used in Kafka. Your log image is no longer available but I remember that I saw in the log, that the subject was not found.
When you request a GET to `/subjects`, what do you see ?

Comment: In `/subjects` I see `["rds","rds_raw"]` and in `/subjects/rds/versions/1` I see `{"subject":"rds","version":1,"id":1,"schema":"{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"rds\",\"namespace\":\"nifi\",\"fields\”:[{<<fields removed for brevity>>}]}"}`

Comment: I just look into the code and it's confirmed what I say in my first answer, you're right when you say that we can retrieve the schema by ID and that's effectively what's happening in Kafka Streams, but I forgot that you're using Kafka Connect, and by looking at the code of the class `AvroConverter` it confirmed my thoughts.
In kafka connect, it's not using only the id but the topic name as well !
So you're using a sink connector, when a record coming, it's try to register the schema into the registry, it will look the subject with the topic name prefix !

Comment: Kafka Streams uses the subject name strategy as well. Every code path leads back to the AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer

Comment: Yes it leads to `AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer` but in Kafka Streams, if you look `GenericAvroDeserializer`, `SpecificAvroDeserializer`  you will note that the topic name is never use for retrieving the schema !!

Comment: It's in the method called : `protected Object deserialize(boolean includeSchemaAndVersion, String topic, Boolean isKey,
                               byte[] payload, Schema readerSchema) `that all the worked is done and here with Kafka Streams, the method variable `String topic` is always `null` when using avro serdes.

But if you look into `AvroConverter` you will note that the topic name is mandatory !

@cricket_007 you're right when you say that the subject name strategy is always used but the method above is not called with the same arguments in Kafka Streams and Kafka Connect.

Comment: I registered a new subject named `rds-value` with the same schema and after some updates to the connector config was able to pull in records!.  I still have to figure out some things, but the main issue is solved.  I completely missed documentation on subject names, but found it now.  Thanks Saïd!

Comment: You're welcome, feel free to ask if you are some questions.